# SequelizeDatabaseError: cannot execute UPDATE in a read-only transaction

Tags: postgresql, update

I'm currently using `Sequelize`, `NodeJS` and `PostgreSQL`. I have users who update their accounts password on first login. Well, today I had this error appear after 3-4 successful logins.

What does this even mean? I did nothing out of the ordinary. A google search does not help me at all as they dont seem to have my problem.

This error appeared on this query:

```
UPDATE "Users" 
SET "password"='-hash-',
"verificationCode"=0,
"startedOn"='2018-04-03 20:45:31.801 +00:00',
"emailVerified"=true,
"updatedAt"='2018-04-03 20:45:31.802 +00:00' 
WHERE "userId" = 84
```

Any help?

Comment: Cannot help if you don't paste the SQL query or at least the sequelize command you use

Comment: You might have connected to a read-only replica, or initiated a read-only transaction.  Maybe something else, but there is way too little information in your question to figure it out.

Comment: I think that nothing strange is in the sql, do you have only one database? or do you have read-only replicas as dezso suggested

Comment: I'm using Heroku. I am pretty sure it is just one database and I wouldn't know if there are replicas. :/ @ImanolY.

Answer (score 3):

It can be caused by these reasons

1) you connected to a follower. Check it, using `select pg_is_in_recovery();` – on master, it will return `false`:

```
test=# select pg_is_in_recovery();
 pg_is_in_recovery
-------------------
 f
(1 row)
```

Of course, you can run UPDATEs only on the master DB.

2) (I suppose this is not your case, but just for completeness I add it) You're working with master DB, but transaction or session was set to be "read only":

```
set session characteristics as transaction read only;
```

or, inside transaction where UPDATE is being executed:

```
set transaction read only;
```

Comment: What does it actually mean? Why would a `db` randomly go into recovery mode or the transaction become read only? I was able to solve the problem by restarting the system.

Comment: @Phil If you are running with a default heroku maybe the problem its with the session, as Nick suggested in his second hypothesis

Comment: @Phil, it’s not about recovery mode. That function tells you if you’re sitting on a replica or not. The name looks so due to the nature of Postgres replication — it was originally based on recovery process (idea was: let’s setup a server being in r covert mode infinitely — and we’ll get a replica!)

Answer (score -1):

Your database might have two different db url/connection strings, one for read only and another one for write. Please check and use the write db url/connecting string.